# Table with fixed position of columns without setting height and width of td and th

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, absolute

I have a table with fixed first three columns. My first three columns are fixed. What I want is that the rest columns should calculate their `height` and `width` automatically, based on their content.

So my CSS looks like this:

```
.outer {
    position:relative;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
.inner {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: calc(100% - 1500px);
    margin-left: 18em;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.8em;
    width: 150px;
    height: 42px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.col1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0em;
    width: 6em;
}

.col2 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 6em;
    width: 6em;
 }

.col3 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 12em;
    width: 6em;
}

.emptyrow {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0em;
    width: 18em;
}
```

This is HTML of table:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col1">Header 1</th>
            <th class="col2">Header 2</th>
            <th class="col3">Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="emptyrow">This column should have value.</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">col 1 - B</td>
            <td class="col2">col 2 - B</td>
            <td class="col3">col 3 - B</td>
            <td>col 4 - B</td>
            <td>col 5 - B</td>
            <td>col 6 - B</td>
            <td>col 7 - B</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">col 1 - C</td>
            <td class="col2">col 2 - C</td>
            <td class="col3">col 3 - C</td>
            <td>col 4 - C</td>
            <td>col 5 - C</td>
            <td>col 6 - C</td>
            <td>col 7 - C</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to avoid setting width and height in `td`, `th`?

I mean to avoid this hardcoded values of `height` and `width`:

```
td, th {
  ...
  width:6em;
  height: 4em;
}
```

Is it possible to do just with plain CSS without JavaScript? If it is not possible to implement with this solution, it would be really great to see another approach.

Requirements:

1. Some scrolled columns can be empty
2. There should be scroll bar to scroll columns from "Header 4"
3. Header 1-3 should be always stay on the same position
4. `Padding` in all columns should be `0.8em`
5. `Width` and `Height` of `td`, `th` should not be hardcoded. They should fit to content.
6. `border-top: 1px solid #ccc;` this property should be kept
7. Highlighting of hovered row

An image of what it is desirable to see:
[image]

Comment: the structure of your table is wrong,https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/site-development/how-to-build-tables-in-html5/ Dont repeat the <th>, its a header

Comment: @Grumpy what if it is necessary to have headers in column places?

Comment: Its forbidden to. You can do this, but the html will not work #easyasthat Otherwise you need to rethink your solution.

Comment: @liqSTAR It would be really great to see another way. Could you show rethought soultion?

Comment: Does it have to be `table`? because as @Grumpy commented this is not valid structure...

Comment: It would be very helpful if you upload a picture showing how the desired table should look like. I'm not completely sure about what you want to achieve.

Comment: @David please, see my updated question

Comment: @Grumpy - I agree with the structure being wrong before the edits; but saying that `<th>` shouldn't repeat is misleading. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th))

Comment: @liqSTAR - What is forbidden? `<th>` elements along a column? That is exactly what [`scope=row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#attr-scope) is meant for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid that there isn't any perfect solution.

I will give you different options and you need to decide what to give up.

---

### Absolutely positioned columns.

✅ Pure CSS - ✅ Old browsers - ❌ Flexible width - ❌ Proper highlight

The key is to set a fixed `width` for the first three columns and then set a `margin-left` property of the `.wrapped` element equal to the total width of the columns.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  margin-left: 18em;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

th, tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
  height: 1em;
}

th:nth-of-type(1),
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0em;
  width: 6em;
}

th:nth-of-type(2),
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
  width: 6em;
}

th:nth-of-type(3),
td:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12em;
  width: 6em;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header-1</th>
        <th>Header-2</th>
        <th>Header-3</th>
        <th>Header-4</th>
        <th>Header-5</th>
        <th>Header-5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - A</td>
        <td>col 2 - A</td>
        <td>col 3 - A</td>
        <td>col 4 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
        <td>col 5 - A</td>
        <td>col 6 - A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - B</td>
        <td>col 2 - B</td>
        <td>col 3 - B</td>
        <td>col 4 - B</td>
        <td>col 5 - B</td>
        <td>col 6 - B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - C</td>
        <td>col 2 - C</td>
        <td>col 3 - C</td>
        <td>col 4 - C</td>
        <td>col 5 - C</td>
        <td>col 6 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

### Absolutely positioned columns + JavaScript.

❌ Pure CSS - ✅ Old browsers - ✅ Flexible width - ❌ Proper highlight

Here, instead of hard-coding the `width` of the columns beforehand, we use JS to calculate and set the `width`.

A much better JS implementation is possible. Take it just as an example.

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
let cols = document.querySelectorAll('th');

let widthCol0 = cols[0].offsetWidth;
let widthCol1 = cols[1].offsetWidth;
let widthCol2 = cols[2].offsetWidth;

stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0]
stylesheet.insertRule('th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1) { left: 0px; position: absolute; width: ' + widthCol0 + 'px;}', 0);
stylesheet.insertRule('th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) { left: ' +  widthCol0 + 'px; position: absolute; width: ' + widthCol1 + 'px;}', 0);
stylesheet.insertRule('th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) { left: ' +  (widthCol0 + widthCol1) + 'px; position: absolute; width: ' + widthCol2 + 'px;}', 0);

wrapper.style.marginLeft = (widthCol0 + widthCol1 + widthCol2) + 'px';
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 15em;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

th, tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
  height: 1em;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header-1</th>
        <th>Header-2</th>
        <th>Header-3</th>
        <th>Header-4</th>
        <th>Header-5</th>
        <th>Header-5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
        <td>col 2 - A</td>
        <td>col 3 - A</td>
        <td>col 4 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
        <td>col 5 - A</td>
        <td>col 6 - A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - B</td>
        <td>col 2 - B</td>
        <td>col 3 - B</td>
        <td>col 4 - B</td>
        <td>col 5 - B</td>
        <td>col 6 - B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - C</td>
        <td>col 2 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
        <td>col 3 - C</td>
        <td>col 4 - C</td>
        <td>col 5 - C</td>
        <td>col 6 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

### Sticky positioned columns.

✅ Pure CSS - ❌ Old browsers - ❌ Flexible width - ✅ Proper highlight

I really like the `position: sticky` solution that @Dominic has shown. It is the way to go if you [don't need to support IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Dropping IE support pays back. You can have the proper highlight and the width of the first three columns will adapt to the content.

Still, even when you don't need to hard-code a `width`, you need to hard-code a `left` property to set at which point the columns become sticky. That kind of defeats the point of having a flexible `width`. There is no way around.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 40em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

th,
tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
  height: 1em;
}

th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1),
th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2),
th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0em;
}

th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 6em;
}

th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 12em;
}

tr:hover td{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header-1</th>
      <th>Header-2</th>
      <th>Header-3</th>
      <th>Header-4</th>
      <th>Header-5</th>
      <th>Header-6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
      <td>col 2 - A</td>
      <td>col 3 - A</td>
      <td>col 4 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
      <td>col 5 - A</td>
      <td>col 6 - A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - B</td>
      <td>col 2 - B</td>
      <td>col 3 - B</td>
      <td>col 4 - B</td>
      <td>col 5 - B</td>
      <td>col 6 - B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - C</td>
      <td>col 2 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
      <td>col 3 - C</td>
      <td>col 4 - C</td>
      <td>col 5 - C</td>
      <td>col 6 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

### Sticky positioned columns + JavaScript.

❌ Pure CSS - ❌ Old browsers - ✅ Flexible width - ✅ Proper highlight

This example has exactly the same HTML and CSS than the one above.

Like in our second example, we use JS to calculate the `width` of the columns. In this case we use it to override the `left` property. Also, the JS code is more straightforward.

Why we set the `left` property in CSS if we are going to set it later with JS? Because if the client doesn't run JS we don't want the columns collapsing completely, breaking our layout.

```js
let cols = document.querySelectorAll('th');

let widthCol0 = cols[0].offsetWidth;
let widthCol1 = cols[1].offsetWidth;

stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
stylesheet.insertRule('th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) { left: ' +  widthCol0 + 'px !important;}', 0);
stylesheet.insertRule('th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) { left: ' +  (widthCol0 + widthCol1) + 'px !important;', 0);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 40em;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

th,
tr:nth-of-type(1) td {
  height: 1em;
}

th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1),
th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2),
th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0em;
}

th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 6em;
}

th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 12em;
}

tr:hover td{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header-1</th>
      <th>Header-2</th>
      <th>Header-3</th>
      <th>Header-4</th>
      <th>Header-5</th>
      <th>Header-6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
      <td>col 2 - A</td>
      <td>col 3 - A</td>
      <td>col 4 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
      <td>col 5 - A</td>
      <td>col 6 - A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - B</td>
      <td>col 2 - B</td>
      <td>col 3 - B</td>
      <td>col 4 - B</td>
      <td>col 5 - B</td>
      <td>col 6 - B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1 - C</td>
      <td>col 2 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
      <td>col 3 - C</td>
      <td>col 4 - C</td>
      <td>col 5 - C</td>
      <td>col 6 - C (WITH_A_LONG_WORD)</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

### Final notes

It is up to you to decide which approach best fits your needs.

Personally, I find the 4th the most powerful because:

- If JS is disabled the columns will collapse beyond the optimal point, but everything will work properly. Just play with the default `left` property in the CSS.
- Under IE11, the table will nicely fall back to a non-fixed columns table.

I don't think that's a big deal. Of course, it you are programming for a intranet where IE11 is the browser of choice, take the first or the second approach.

Comment: oh, thank you very much! It is really cool! It would be really great to have a solution with `position: absolute`. Could you add a class to highlight hovered row?

Comment: David, I have just one question. When I highlight row, then some columns with `position: absolute` are highlighted differently with columns which are scrollable. Is it possible to fix this behavior?

Comment: David I am just wondering is it possible to make the first three columns `position: absolute`, but without setting hardcoded `width`?

Comment: Regarding the highlight, it is a known issue with fixed columns and the reason why I used `tr:hover td {...}` instead of the more strightforward `tr:hover {...}`. Regarding `position: absolute` without harcoded `width` I'm afraid it is not possible. Anyway, now I'm on the run, let me have a look to both things when I come back.

Comment: ok, please, show an example with `sticky`,but without setting hardcoded `width`?

Comment: I left you several examples. Play with them and let me know :)

Comment: thank you very much! What a neat answer! Have a nice day, CSS master!

Comment: @Learner - Thank you for your words. Have a nice day you too!

Comment: It is very useful and details, your solution worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You should use sticky cells instead, this will keep the columns as part of the document flow. Also if you want the columns to react to content width you need to remove `table-layout: fixed`.

Also you can remove the `max-width` if you want, it's an example to add some sensible max width to the columns after which they will get an ellipses (see last column).

```css
.scroller {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table, table * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

/* borders should be on th/td so the table can collapse them */
th, td {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0; /* Default padding should be removed */
}

/* padding, overflow ellipses etc behaves better if
   content is wrapped in an inner element */
.inner-cell {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
.sticky-2 {
  left: 6em;
}
.sticky-3 {
  left: 12em;
}
/* Behaves better if width is set on inner el (or it moves 1px when scrolling) */
.sticky .inner-cell {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky sticky-1"><div class="inner-cell">Stick 1</div></th>
        <th class="sticky sticky-2"><div class="inner-cell">Stick 2</div></th>
        <th class="sticky sticky-3"><div class="inner-cell">Stick 3</div></th>
        <th><div class="inner-cell">Normal 1</div></th>
        <th><div class="inner-cell">Normal 2</div></th>
        <th><div class="inner-cell">Normal 3</div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky sticky-1"><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Val 1</div></td>
        <td class="sticky sticky-2"><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Val 2</div></td>
        <td class="sticky sticky-3"><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Val 3</div></td>
        <td><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Normal 1</div></td>
        <td><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Normal 2 looooong</div></td>
        <td><div class="inner-cell">Sticky Normal 3 something really long we don't want to display all of this</div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do not have enough knowledge to apply your answer. Could you apply your styles to my html elements?

Comment: Just being picky: with `position: sticky` the element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document **until** it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed. Very good solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using  tag repeatedly, avoid that.
Second thing is that to set auto width and height use

```css
th {
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, if I set to `auto`, then horizontal scroll bar will be dissapeared and rows are collapsed